# jquery tooltip with image

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking to make a custom tooltip using Jquery that on mouse hover, a box (tooltip) comes up with a picture and some text info.

I am modifying a site for class, the site I chose was d2jsp.org. What I am trying to do is when I hover over my account link, a tooltip comes up with the pic and text.

My HTML does the tooltip text without any Jquery, but I need Jquery so I am trying to use a picture as well.

Here's a snippet of the HTML-

```
</div><div class="bar"><ul class="barR"><li><a href="http://forums.d2jsp.org/pm.php">Messages: 11</a></li><li><a href="http://forums.d2jsp.org/gold.php">Forum Gold: <b>0.01</b></a></li><li><a href="http://forums.d2jsp.org/guild.php?a=1">My Guild</a></li><li><a href="http://forums.d2jsp.org/events.php">My Events</a></li><li><a href="http://forums.d2jsp.org/track.php">Topic Tracker</a></li></ul><ul class="barL"><li>Hello,<a href="http://forums.d2jsp.org/user.php?i=476515" title="Last Seen: 0 seconds ago <br>

Last Post: 2 days ago <br>

Status: N/A" img="">Hockeygod9911<div class="sX s1"></div></a></li><li><a href="http://forums.d2jsp.org/login.php?c=8">Log Out</a></li><li><a href="http://forums.d2jsp.org/settings.php">Settings</a></li></ul><div class="c"></div></div><table width="100%">
```

Adding in title="X" add the tooltip for what I need the text to do. But I need to add the image.

http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-content
The Jquery ui site gives this code:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( document ).tooltip({
      items: "img, [data-geo], [title]",
      content: function() {
        var element = $( this );
        if ( element.is( "[data-geo]" ) ) {
          var text = element.text();
          return "<img class='map' alt='" + text +
            "' src='http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?" +
            "zoom=11&size=350x350&maptype=terrain&sensor=false&center=" +
            text + "'>";
        }
        if ( element.is( "[title]" ) ) {
          return element.attr( "title" );
        }
        if ( element.is( "img" ) ) {
          return element.attr( "alt" );
        }
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
```

I have no idea what the 2nd and 3rd if statements are really doing there, nor do I have any idea what [data-geo] is. It also uses some code im not familiar with (items).

So what I am understanding (and i obviously understand it incorrectly) is the items are like objects? The variable element is this [data-geo] which i dont get, and it links to google to get the image.

This is what I have edited so far of the Jquery -

```
  $(function() {
    $( document ).tooltip({
      items: "img, [img], [title]",
      content: function() {
        var element = $( this );
        if ( element.is( "[img]" ) ) {
          var text = element.text();
          return "<img class='avatar' alt='" + text +
            "' src='d2jsp Forums_files/avatar.gif" +
            "zoom=11&size=65x57&sensor=false&center=" +
            text + "'>";
        }
        if ( element.is( "[title]" ) ) {
          return element.attr( "title" );
        }
        if ( element.is( "img" ) ) {
          return element.attr( "alt" );
        }
      }
    });
  });
```

Im just looking to have it bring up a pic from the folder it's located in.